# During init, Is there any way to avoid messaging self when dealing with properties from a super-class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I've read that you're not supposed to send messages to 'self' during an init.  Unfortunately, you can't directly access the ivars belonging to your superclass (as far as I can tell).  This leads to the situation where you need to access / set up the superclasses ivar in some way, but have no way to do so other than messaging self.  (For reference, I'm writing custom UIControls to encapsulate repeated concepts in my application; while a lot of the logic is shared, and thus belongs in a superclass, the exact layout of each control needs to vary).

For example, a custom control needs to have a button.  That button is arranged different compared to each other object in the view depending on the subclass in question, so I need to reference it for layout.  As far as I'm aware, unlike ViewControlllers, UIViews don't have any callbacks to let you know about lifecycle events like 'willAppear' or 'didLoad'; init is the only place to place the code -- and the tutorials I've read on creating custom UIControls put it there, as well.

Am I misunderstanding something, or do I have no choice *but* to violate the rule about messaging self in my scenario?  (Or create an extra method that has to be called after init...  creating a new convention that's basically saying 'first you init, then you REALLY init'!)

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, you can't directly access the ivars belonging to your superclass (as far as I can tell)

That is only in situations when the base class declares ivars `@private`. If it does not, you can access ivars using the `->` operator on `self`, like this:

```
self->myBaseIntVar = 123;
```

By default, ivars have `@protected` access, so you should be able to access them unless the designers of your superclass have specifically withdrew this possibility by specifying private access.

> Am I misunderstanding something, or do I have no choice but to violate the rule about messaging self in my scenario?

Another choice is passing values to the designated initializer of your base class:

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super initWithSomeProperty:123]) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Huh... I thought accessing ivars could only be done using the _<varname> approach. (Edit:  in fact, self-><varname> does *not* work -- throws compiler error)  Live and learn.  Also, passing values to the designated initializer doesn't work because I really do have totally different layouts for each control.  for example, one had a title above and a text field below the 'shared' UIButton, while another has neither of those, just the button.  The shared logic focuses on how to change the button depending on certain inputs, but the initializer needs to set up the constraints between each object.

Comment: @RonLugge When you access ivars from your own class, the `self->` part is implied, but you can always add that, too, i.e. `self->_myIvar` is going to work the same as `_myIvar`. Also note that if the property in the base is synthesized, you may need to add an underscore `_` to the name as well.

Comment: I thought access to ivars using `->` was now discouraged by Apple because they are considering changing the way ivars are stored in the runtime.  Not sure why I think that, probably something I saw in a WWDC session.

Comment: @RonLugge If the classes are drastically different, you may reconsider the decision to inherit one from the other. You could share the logic between your two classes by using a common "helper" class with methods that take an instance of your view as a parameter, and deals with consuming inputs and changing the buttons the way you specify.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight D'oh, you're right, I forgot the _ on my ivar.  I feel stupid.  Oh, and I think your last message is mis-directed.  I'll also think through your advice on helper class...  I'll need to figure out how that works, though I suddenly have ideas.

Comment: @mttrb I would not be surprised by such a change at all - I never particularly liked the way the language adopted C's convention to access ivars through a pointer, especially since there are so many ways to associate state with objects these days.

Comment: Looks like I was thinking about session 404, Advances in Objective-C, from WWDC 2013 and it looks like I'm wrong.  It was raw isa access that is being discouraged, e.g. `self->isa`, not all pointer access to ivars.